# Getting H13 Error when visiting deployed Heroku Site

Tags: node.js, heroku, npm

I am able to deploy my heroku app, but when I visit the site I get an "Application Error"

I check the logs and I get this error.

```
2020-12-31T19:11:51.183872+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
2020-12-31T19:11:51.184111+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! errno 1
2020-12-31T19:11:51.188994+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! donaghmoyne-gaa@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
2020-12-31T19:11:51.189093+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Exit status 1
2020-12-31T19:11:51.189223+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!
2020-12-31T19:11:51.189332+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! Failed at the donaghmoyne-gaa@1.0.0 start script.
2020-12-31T19:11:51.189430+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2020-12-31T19:11:51.198554+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-31T19:11:51.198755+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
2020-12-31T19:11:51.198866+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2020-12-31T19_11_51_190Z-debug.log
2020-12-31T19:11:51.248899+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-31T19:11:51.177846+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/" host=donaghmoyne-gaa.herokuapp.com request_id=6e2f3c82-5678-4247-ba5f-7f7d2cf38362 fwd="80.233.38.196" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=28205ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-12-31T19:11:51.293085+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2020-12-31T19:11:51.296451+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-31T19:11:53.293694+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-12-31T19:11:55.043398+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-12-31T19:11:55.043410+00:00 app[web.1]: > donaghmoyne-gaa@1.0.0 start /app
2020-12-31T19:11:55.043410+00:00 app[web.1]: > node app.js
2020-12-31T19:11:55.043411+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-12-31T19:11:55.550523+00:00 app[web.1]: Listening on Port 3769
2020-12-31T19:11:55.964632+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2020-12-31T19:12:25.618344+00:00 heroku[router]: sock=backend at=error code=H18 desc="Server Request Interrupted" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=donaghmoyne-gaa.herokuapp.com request_id=d65a38d1-6b26-4797-8e82-4058fe54f5d6 fwd="80.233.38.196" dyno=web.1 connect=5000ms service=25004ms status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

I am really not sure what is causing the error,

Thank you

Comment: "Unable to visit Heroku Site I visited" you might want to clear that title up. I have no idea what that should mean.

Comment: Does that look better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the problem was, I was not connecting the Atlas DB properly.

I found this video and it helped. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WVxG1Smf92o&ab_channel=Kristian